# How to navigate facebook websites on buttontap in sencha touch2

Tags: html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i have defined a button. click of the button i need to navigate to Facebook login page.  when i click the button its going to OnfacebookButtonTap function getting alert message facebook. in this function i need to call Facebook URL. i want show face book login page. how to archive in Sencha Touch. Could anyone tell me how to do this. Thank you

Here is my button tap function:

```
OnfacebookButtonTap:function () {
    alert('facebook')
    //https://www.facebook.com/
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `window.location`. It's working fine :

```
OnfacebookButtonTap:function () {
    window.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/';
},
```